# Getting neighbourhood boundaries from Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

While using Google Maps' "What's here" menu I realised it draws neighbourhood borders, as shown here with the dotted line:

[image: Taken from Google Maps]

Is it possible to get this data in Google Maps API and make my map draw neighbourhood borders of a given point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, Google Maps API does not provide neighborhood data. There's a [Zillow API](http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/neighborhood-boundaries.htm) for neighborhoods in the US, I'm not familiar with ones any outside the US.

Comment: Google Maps API now gives neighborhood data.

Comment: @in-code-veritas we geocode neighborhoods but do not return the border. We'll return a point.