# How to retrieve a static map showing city or municipality boundaries

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I'm not sure where to start looking in the documentation, but I'm trying to load map images of cities with their boundaries outlined.

Like this...

[image: Fort Worth map including boundaries]

Any help getting started would be greatly appreciated, I'm pretty new to the maps api.

Thanks

Comment: You might try using: http://www.openstreetmap.org/

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no way to request a map with boundaries automatically rendered on it.  Your best bet is to pull the polygon information from another system and render using an [encoded polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#EncodedPolylines) if you're using the Static Map API or regular [overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Polylines) in the JavaScript API.

Answer (score 0):

Google Static Map API

[Here it is](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)

Comment: I'd like to see an example. I can't get it to work. Here's a static map API link without the boundaries, that at the same zoom on maps.google.com, shows boundaries.  http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=32.725409,%20-97.320849&zoom=10&size=400x400&sensor=false

Comment: @HeitorChang: Can you link to the map with boundaries? I don't see them in the Google Maps map.

Comment: At close zooms, the boundaries disappear. http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Fort+Worth,+TX,+United+States&hl=en&ll=32.814978,-97.289429&spn=0.626696,1.352692&sll=-23.550633,-46.653168&sspn=0.010681,0.021136&oq=fort+wort&hnear=Fort+Worth,+Tarrant,+Texas&t=m&z=10

Comment: I looked through this pretty close and don't see any obvious way to display borders at any zoom level. Am i missing something obvious? Do you have to pass in encoded data to draw out the boundaries?

Answer (score 0):

here, some links to help you:

[Geographical boundaries of states/provinces -> Google Maps Polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814169/geographical-boundaries-of-states-provinces-google-maps-polygon)

[EInsert extension](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/einsert.htm)

[Boundary Draw - Google Map Application](https://www.elance.com/samples/boundary-draw-google-map-application/25308308/)

[Getting neighbourhood boundaries from Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056810/getting-neighbourhood-boundaries-from-google-maps-api)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441467/can-you-draw-custom-search-boundaries-in-google-map

[Ability to draw boundaries on Google Maps](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/50b0173e5d3d7c39?pli=1)