# get boundaries of neighborhoods in Google maps api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I can see in Google Maps it shows the boundaries of neighborhoods

(e.g : https://www.google.com/search?q=south+of+market&oq=south+of+market&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4749j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8)

Is there a way to get this information in Google Maps API? And draw the polygons of the neighborhoods?

Comment: See my response below.

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time Google does not provide this information. There has always been a mis-match between the maps application and services provided by the api (quite understandably so).

Question posted here identical: [Getting neighbourhood boundaries from Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056810/getting-neighbourhood-boundaries-from-google-maps-api)

Suggests using the [zillow](http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/neighborhood-boundaries.htm) api for US boundaries if this is any use to you.

Comment: zillow seems to no longer have this.   www.boundaries-io.com has a API for this.

Answer (score 0):

The boundaries are actually part of the image (drawn to canvas) for that particular location, magnification level, etc.

Whether the data is saved beforehand as a series of images that make up the map view, or are drawn to the image canvas after a request, one thing *seems* to be evident:

When you type in and search for an area/neighborhood your browser receives those images with the red outline and light-red shading already applied. Therefore this appears to occur server-side (before your browser receives the image).

[image: Example of image received by browser]

Unless I am incorrect it seems that without google's assistance it is unlikely to obtain this data.